# How to download contents of folder from SP Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online

In the `All Files` section of SP Designer 2013 I have a folder named `Apps` that has all of my front-end stuff (JS/HTML/CSS). What is the simplest way to download / copy the contents of that folder to my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can open that URL in Internet Explorer. Or you can click Browse button from SPD**

[image]

**And now from Ribbon choose to open in Explorer.**

[image]

**Now you can copy folder/files and Paste in your local folder.**

***Update***

Since the folder is in Root we wont be able to browse it in Explorer View. Here is a workaround

1. First copy the folder from SPD and Paste it inside a temp location (Say Assets)
2. Now go inside Assets folder and Paste it
3. Now Follow as I said above.. Open in IE and Then Open with Explorer
4. After copying you can delete it from Assets folder.

Comment: When I go to `http://staging.csntoday.org/Apps` I get Page Not Found error.

Comment: There is a greyed out option for 'Preview In browser', screenshot http://i.imgur.com/ojWj5rv.png

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surprising nobody mentioned [SPFileZilla](https://spfilezilla.codeplex.com/). I wanted to do the same thing and stumbled across this fantastic piece of software. Works as defined - an FTP software for SharePoint and makes it super easy to copy folders and files to the local disk without the need for mapping any URL.

Answer (score -1):

1. `WIN KEY + E`
2. write in url `\\YOURSITE\Apps`  press enter
3. `CTRL+A`, `CTRL+C`

Comment: Not working for me, here's a screenshot http://i.imgur.com/obnw92z.png